# How to set default value to my file input tag?

Tags: javascript, php, input, input-type-file

I have this code

```
<input name="GG" type="file" value="< ?php echo $data['image'] ?>">
```

I hope this can give default value in form edit, but it's not work.
How to set default value in my input tag?

Comment: Please, improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: Simple input tag <input type="text" value="defaultValue">

Comment: you can't set default value for type="file". See the doc: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp. The value attribute cannot be used with <input type="file">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

See the docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp. The value attribute cannot be used with `<input type="file">`